# Sobolev type embedding

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider a compact manifold $M$ and a point $q \in M$. Let us say that 
that the following inequality holds:
$$
\Vert \varphi u\Vert_{L^p} \leq C\Vert \varphi u\Vert_{H^1},$$ where $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(M \setminus \{q\})$, that is, $\varphi$ is smooth and compactly supported away from $q$, and $C$ is independent of $\varphi$ and $u$. If we know that $u \in H^1 \cap L^p$, can we conclude from the above that 
$$\Vert u\Vert_{L^p} \leq C\Vert u\Vert_{H^1}?$$

Edit: It seems that it suffices to claim that there exists a sequence $\varphi_k$ such that $\varphi_k u \to u$ in $L^p$-norm and $\varphi_k u \to u$ in $H^1$-norm. But I cannot justify the existence of such a sequence.

Comment: Looking for $\varphi_k$ is reasonable. But the existence of $\varphi_k$ fails in one dimension: you cannot approximate, say, the constant function $1$ in $H^1(S^1)$ by functions vanishing at a point. Is $M$ of dimension $n\ge 2$? Then a single point has zero $H^1$-capacity, meaning that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth bump function that is $1$ near this point, and has $H^1$ norm $<\epsilon$. This should help.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Yes, $\text{dim }M \geq 2$. From what you say, we should be able to find a sequence $u_n \in C^\infty_c(M\setminus \{q\})$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^1$-norm. That, together with the first inequality, will settle the question, right?

Comment: Yes, this should work.